# Can I resolve Azure Key Vault privately if I modify the default DNS Zone name?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to create a key vault that uses a private DNS zone with a non-default zone name (**vault.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net** instead of **privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net**) and linking it with my VNET with a private link. Once the zone is created, my public DNS (**myabcvault.vault.azure.net**) should resolve to my private DNS zone (**myabcvault.vault.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net**) but it doesn't. When I use the standard DNS zone naming convention, it works fine. Is there a way I can achieve what I am expecting? The reason I am using a non-default DNS zone name is that I want to link two key vaults to the same VNET and keep both of their zones separate (as they are in different resource groups).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the default DNS Zone name of a private endpoint for Azure Key Vault

If you modify the default DNS Zone name, your Key Vault public DNS will not resolve to your private DNS Zone unless you own that DNS

Instead, you can use your custom DNS for your private endpoint

You can link your two key vaults to the same VNET with the default DNS Zone name as follows:

- Kv1.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net
- Kv2.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I have two default DNS zones (for different key vaults) and link them to the same VNET?

Comment: Yeah we can have two default DNS Zones (for different key vaults) in the same VNET